# DB2 SQL - Possible to query a list of values without using "or" for each row of values?

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I have a list of values and I am wondering if it's possible to query by said list, rather than having to do an "or" for each row of values or add them into a table and query the table (as I'm about to do)

Say, for example, my list is;

```
010, 46793, '329', '10'
011, 46798, '322', '12'
012, 33333, '111', '14'
```

I'd like to query like this;

```
SELECT VALUE1, VALUE2, VALUE3
  FROM MYTABLE
 WHERE (VALUEW VALUEX, VALUEY, VALUEZ) in(
        (010, 46793, '329', '10'),
        (011, 46798, '322', '12'),
        (012, 33333, '111', '14'))
```

(This fails on syntax)

Rather than having to do;

```
SELECT VALUE1, VALUE2, VALUE3
  FROM MYTABLE
 WHERE (VALUEW VALUEX, VALUEY, VALUEZ) = (010, 46793, '329', '10')
    OR (VALUEW VALUEX, VALUEY, VALUEZ) = (011, 46798, '322', '12')
    OR (VALUEW VALUEX, VALUEY, VALUEZ) = (012, 33333, '111', '14')
```

Please note that something like;

```
SELECT VALUE1, VALUE2, VALUE3
  FROM MYTABLE
 WHERE VALUEW IN(010, 011, 012)
   AND VALUEX IN(46793, 46798, 33333) 
   AND VALUEY IN('329', '322', '111')
   AND VALUEZ IN('10', '12', '14')
```

Will not work in this scenario.

For example, if the below value existed in "MYTABLE";

```
011, 33333, '329', '10'
```

The aforementioned SQL would retrieve it, yet it's not on my list.

Comment: Which operating-system runs your Db2-server? (Z/OS, OS/400, Linux/Unix/Windows). The syntax can vary.

Comment: Good point, I should've mentioned that - It's running on an iSeries (OS/400) at version; V6R1M0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the syntax below (it is valid on Db2 LUW v11) not sure of Db2 for i:

```
SELECT VALUE1, VALUE2, VALUE3
FROM  MYTABLE
where (VALUEW, VALUEX, VALUEY, VALUEZ) in ( values
        (010, 46793, '329', '10'),
        (011, 46798, '322', '12'),
        (012, 33333, '111', '14')
        );
```

Comment: Worked a treat, didn't realise you could use values in anything other than an insert, thanks.

Comment: Works on Db2 for i, checked on V7R3 system.

Answer (score 0):

Altenate solution for non-LUW DB2:

```
WITH mylist(w,x,y,z) AS (
SELECT  010, 46793, '329', '10' FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 UNION ALL
SELECT  011, 46798, '322', '12' FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 UNION ALL
SELECT  012, 33333, '111', '14' FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 
)
SELECT VALUE1, VALUE2, VALUE3
FROM MYTABLE
INNER JOIN mylist
ON (VALUEW, VALUEX, VALUEY, VALUEZ)=(w,x,y,z)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got an alternate solution for non-LUW DB2 that makes use of the `XMLTABLE` function. This allows many more rows than the `SYSDUMMY1 UNION ALL` approach.

```
SELECT TEST_NM, ITM_CD
FROM XMLTABLE('$doc/xml/node'
    PASSING XMLPARSE('<xml>
        <node test-nm="ABC 123" itm-cd="215" />
        <node test-nm="DEF 345" itm-cd="151" />
        <node test-nm="GHI 678" itm-cd="412" />
        <node test-nm="JKL 901" itm-cd="410" />
        <node test-nm="MNO 234" itm-cd="875" />
        <node test-nm="PQR 567" itm-cd="249" />
        <node test-nm="STU 890" itm-cd="817" />
    </xml>') AS "doc"
    COLUMNS TEST_NM VARCHAR(30) PATH '@test-nm',
        ITM_CD INTEGER PATH '@itm-cd') AS Q;
```